# "Structural type guard" works with `if`, but not as array filter predicate

Tags: typescript, types, structural-typing

I have a union type (`Pet` in the example below) that combines multiple object types which each have a `type` property indicating their type. Sometimes I have an array of the union type (`Pet[]`) and need to `.filter()` it based on the `type` property. That in itself works perfectly fine, but in order to avoid redundant type declarations I want to make sure that the result of the `.filter()` call is automatically typed properly.

[User-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) seemed like the perfect solution for this, so I implemented one that just checks the `type` property and narrows the type to `{ type: 'something' }` *without* explicitly declaring the full type (this one's called `isCatLike` below). I tried using it inside an `if` and it correctly narrowed my type from `Pet` to `Cat`.

I then tried to use it as a predicate for `.filter()` and this time the type **wasn't narrowed at all**. The resulting array was still typed as `Pet[]` although my `if` experiment had shown that the type guard was generally able to narrow from `Pet` to `Cat`.

As another experiment I tried to change the type guard slightly and make the type predicate more explicit (`is Cat` instead of `is { type: 'cat' }` and suddenly the `.filter()` call **correctly narrowed the type** from `Pet[]` to `Cat[]` (this function is called `isCat` below).

```
type Cat = { type: 'cat'; name: string; purrs: boolean }
type Dog = { type: 'dog'; name: string; woofs: boolean }
type Pet = Cat | Dog

declare const pets: Pet[]
const isCatLike = (pet: any): pet is { type: 'cat' } => pet.type === 'cat'
const isCat = (pet: Pet): pet is Cat => pet.type === 'cat'

for (const pet of pets) {
  if (isCatLike(pet)) {
    pet // Cat -> Correct!
  }
  if (isCat(pet)) {
    pet // Cat
  }
}

const catLikes = pets.filter(isCatLike)
catLikes // Pet[] -> Incorrect!

const cats = pets.filter(isCat)
cats // Cat[]
```

*[Open the example on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsKBeKBvKpIC4oHIDGCuA3FAHZwC2EOAzsAE4CWZA5qWAK4MO04BGAe0EAbCHDJQAvgFgAUJmgARQa2RoM4GngAmqkuSrb6zNqQDuwgGZ8oQ0eMmyFWqAAUIiFPEQAfKCqs8vI6EPgicAzQ+IJk9FCQwLYewADaALryMXGITLQ+ADJMANbQKAAUiTgSIACUOIlQeRqKOARE0sgAfAmeAHSKyEgo7cC4WbHxeT7qlZ44KfW9ubSwCN3LA67DI4RjwXJWggxQ5dnxjYJWy7S1aPJQTdfl0whFpXPAtXeoD4-LUAA9IC1ogALQ9GDHKL4YAAQj+zkeTGer2An2+9zk-wBwNBiPkzgmOSge3eEFWKEStD6ViYImAEAYL3ybxKEFqWTZpVWeJSGSgEKgAEkyDEeGF4Qdzog9pSbrT6YzmWjOXI5UCQT4MvIgA) to inspect the types yourself.*

The problem now is that I can't use the more explicit approach (illustrated by the `isCat` function) because my actual code has a lot more types in the union and there the predicate is also *created by a function* (`isType(type: string)`).

So what I'm wondering at the moment is this:

Why does my "structural type guard" work in the context of an `if` statement, but not as a predicate for filtering an array? Shouldn't it work exactly the same way in both cases? Am I doing something wrong or have I hit a limitation of the type system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to how the types for `Array.filter` are written:

```
interface Array<T>
    // This is the signature that enables the array to be a different type
    filter<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];

    // Normal signature that returns the same type of array
    filter(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: readonly T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];
}
```

The key bit of that signature is `<S extends T>`, where in this case, `T` is `Pet` and `S` *would* be `{ type: "cat" }`.  However, `{ type: "cat" }` does not extend `Pet`, so the signature does not apply, so it falls into the normal filter signature.

---

It works in the single element case, because TS's narrowing logic is actually a bit smarter than can be expressed in the signature for `.filter` - it actually combines the result of the type guard and the original type - something like `Pet & { type: "cat" }` which is the same as `Cat`.

Answer (score 0):

From the handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

> pet is Fish is our type predicate in this example. A predicate takes the form parameterName is Type, where parameterName must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature. Any time isFish is called with some variable, TypeScript will narrow that variable to that specific type **if the original type is compatible**.

I would guess that since the original type is `any` in the type guard, TS can't narrow it down at all, if you swap `any` for `Cat` you even get a compilation error saying that `{type: 'cat'}` is not assignable to `Cat` cause of missing the other two props.

I took that as a hint and made those other props optional:
`type Cat = { type: 'cat'; name?: string; purrs?: boolean }`

Your predicate starts working as you want it to then.

Comment: _"I would guess that since the original type is any in the type guard, TS can't narrow it down at all"_ — Isn't that exactly what it does inside the `if` though? I get why you say _"`{type: 'cat'}` is not assignable to Cat cause of missing the other two props"_, but why is that suddenly not a concern inside the `if`? That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: It knows that in your array of `Pet`s, there can be only dogs or cats. And it knows that the type `{type: 'cat'}` is NOT assignable to either `Dog` or `Cat`, so when filtering with that typeguard, the results are still just an array of `Pet`s,

Comment: I understand that, but what's different about the `if`? Couldn't I say the same thing about the `pet` variable there? That it can only be of type `Cat` or `Dog`? TypeScript uses exactly the same "incomplete" type guard there, but somehow comes to the _different_ conclusion that `pet` _is in fact_ of type `Cat` in that context. I feel like TypeScript is being a little inconsistent in how it narrows types here, no?