# How to filter an array of objects by type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that filters an array of objects by their `type` property:

```
export const retrieveLayoutChangeActions = (data: GetOperations['included']) =>
  data.filter(d => d.type === 'layoutChangeAction') as LayoutChangeAction[];
```

The `data` parameter may or may not include more types rather than the `LayoutChangeAction[]`, e.g. `(LayoutChangeAction | Product)[]`. How do I extend the type definition such that it supports any type as long as it includes `LayoutChangeAction`?

I tried using generics,

```
export const retrieveLayoutChangeActions = <T extends LayoutChangeAction>(data: T[]) =>
  data.filter(d => d.type === 'layoutChangeAction') as LayoutChangeAction[];
```

But that results in a `TS2345: Argument of type '(LayoutChangeAction | Product)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LayoutChangeAction[]'.`

The type definitions are large, but here is the property that makes each type unique:

```
interface LayoutChangeAction extends BaseResponse<'layoutChangeAction'> {
  type: 'layoutChangeAction';
  /* unique attributes... */
}

interface Product extends BaseResponse<'product'> {
  type: 'product';
  /* unique attributes... */
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps just add a little example of 2 objects to illustrate what `LayoutChangeAction` and `Product` look like (or their interfaces)? It sounds like `Product` has all of the fields that `LayoutChangeAction` has, and some more. If that is the case, then probably the definition of your `Product` interface is incorrect.

Comment: I don't see why you need generics here, instead of  `(data: T[])`, don't you have some parent class/interface/type you can use?  like `(data: Action)`, something that includes the `type` property

Comment: @zapl Yes, my interfaces extend `BaseResponse<T extends ResponseType>` where `ResponseType` is a union of different possible types (e.g. `'product' | 'layoutChangeAction'`). I don't see how I can use it to fix my problem though.

Comment: You can probably do `export const retrieveLayoutChangeActions = (data: { type: string }[]) => data.filter((d) => d.type === 'layoutChangeAction') as LayoutChangeAction[]` because you don't use the generics for anything useful besides trying to find a broader definition of "somthing that has a type property". If your `BaseResponse` has that property you might be able to do `data: BaseResponse<any>` or something similar as well. But your code could also accept `object[]` and simply test if there's a type field in an  object, since you're interested in the return type, not the type of the others

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Structural type guard" works with \`if\`, but not as array filter predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683063/structural-type-guard-works-with-if-but-not-as-array-filter-predicate)

Answer (score 0):

If type is your differentiator you could use `{ type: string }[]` as your data argument.

Are you sure you need retrieve layout change function? `.filter(isLayoutChange)` is somewhat more expressive.

```
function isLayoutChange(t: { type: string }): t is Layout change {
  return t.type === 'layoutChangeAction'
}
```

t is Layout change is a type guard. In code paths where it returns true, t is narrowed to LayoutChange.